# What is this function doing (softmax)

Tags: c#, neural-network, softmax

What is this "ih" and "ho" in this function . It is softmax activation function I am not able to understand the string check reason.

```
public double sim(double x, string layer)
    {
      // Determine max
      double max = double.MinValue;
      if (layer == "ih")
        max = (ihSum0 > ihSum1) ? ihSum0 : ihSum1;
      else if (layer == "ho")
        max = (hoSum0 > hoSum1) ? hoSum0 : hoSum1;

      // Compute scale
      double scale = 0.0;
      if (layer == "ih")
        scale = Math.Exp(ihSum0 - max) + Math.Exp(ihSum1 - max);
      else if (layer == "ho")
        scale = Math.Exp(hoSum0 - max ) + Math.Exp(hoSum1 - max);

      return Math.Exp(x - max) / scale;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not too hard to be understood. You may want to take some time to look at how the function implement neural network activation function behavior.

In neural network, it is typical for you to have activation function which receives sets of input and decides which would trigger the function based on maximum value (among the inputs).

Likewise for your case.

It seems like there are **two sets** of input (each "set" called "layer", thus there are two layers) codenamed "ih" and "ho". Each set further has two elements called `Sum0` and `Sum1` and thus making combinations of four inputs:
    1. `ihSum0` and `ihSum1` (for `ih` layer) 
    2. `hoSum0` and `hoSum1` (for `ho` layer)

Whatever the `ih`, `ho`, and `layer` mean in your context, you would understand better. But the function simply checks which input set (or "layer") is to be used (that is "ih" or "ho") to determine two variables (`max` and `scale`).

```
if (layer == "ih")
    max = (ihSum0 > ihSum1) ? ihSum0 : ihSum1;
else if (layer == "ho")
    max = (hoSum0 > hoSum1) ? hoSum0 : hoSum1;
```

which ultimately (together with `x`), will be used to determine the final output of your function.

```
return Math.Exp(x - max) / scale;
```

Comment: For me it seems that `ih` could stand for `input->hidden` and `ho` for `hidden->output`.